# upgrade TFS 2010 and TFS 2012 RC to TFS 2012 final

Tags: tfs

Currently our company is using TFS 2010 and TFS 2012 RC.
we need to upgrade TFS 2010 and TFS 2012 RC to TFS 2012 final on different server,
that already people are using the TFS 2010 and TFS 2012 RC environment.

Comment: Make sure you have backup of TFS SQL databases.
Then on new server install TFS 2012 (RTM) and install only application pool by UPGRADE process in installation wizard then attach collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not really sure what the question is here so I'll give you some links with information on the upgrade process. If you have specific questions, feel free to ask.

Upgrade guidance put together by the TFS Rangers: http://vsarupgradeguide.codeplex.com/releases

Official install and admin guides: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29035

A link to a book that covers the topic: https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/181289

Answer (score 1):

The TFS integration project is what you want.

http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

We've used it successfully to consolidate two TFS 2010 servers with multiple project collections into a single TFS 2012 with a single project collection. It also provides two-way synchronisation so that a gradual migration of users is possible.